# Angular, How to display text without the HTML tags?

Tags: html, angular

I have a string stored in my localStorage with the HTML tags since I use ngx-quill (Angular Rich Text Editor) which stores the data in HTML formatted text.

This is what my localStorage looks like:
[image]

As you can see from the picture above, in description, there is p tags.

Is there any way I can display it on Angular page without the tags?
[image]

Comment: You should user [innerHTML] for that, for example:
`<div [innerHTML]="item.description"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: **[innerHTML]** for that, for example:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data.description"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use innerHTML and make sure that you trust the HTML if it contains script tag else Angular will throw an error.

Do the following, create a safeHTML pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml' })
    export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
        constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    
        transform(html: string): any {
            return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
        }
    }
```

and then use this with innerHTML like this:

```
<span [innerHTML]="description" | sanitizeHtml"></span>
```

Comment: that is not how you sanitize, that's how you 'trust' content as-is which you shouldn't. please refer to https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize